# 'statsfminbx' error with MATLAB built-in factoran()

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, mathematical-optimization

Could someone please assist in debugging the following error, while performing *factor analysis* on my data?

```
factoran(x,2) ; %where x is <250*10> double =>
Undefined function 'statsfminbx' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
Error in factoran
[Psi1, nll, lagrange, err, output] = ...
```

After looking into the codes **(from line 269)**, it sounds like for some reasons maximum likelihood estimate of the loadings could not be obtained, thus I look for a way around to overcome this matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `x` is a 250*10 array of doubles, and not a cell array of some sort? When you type `whos x`, does it say `250x10 double`, or does it say the class is `cell`?

Comment: Error occurs since i made a copy of `factoran.m` in another directory outside the default toolbox folder. Thus the error message is merely misleading as it is unrelated to some `cell type` i originally thought of like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`statsfminbx` is a [private function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html) to `factoran`, and can only be called by `factoran` itself.

If you create a folder called `private` and put code in it, that code can only be called from code in the immediate parent folder (it's actually only on the path at all, for code in the immediate parent folder). This is a useful technique to avoid polluting the namespace.

The original `factoran` is in `toolbox\stats\stats\factoran.m`, and can therefore call `toolbox\stats\stats\private\statsfminbx.m`.

When you made a copy of `factoran` and placed it outside the default folder, your copy can no longer access the private function `statsfminbx`. You may try making your own copy of the `private` folder, placing it in the appropriate place beneath your copy of `factoran`, and putting a copy of `statsfminbx` in it. (On the other hand, you may find that you subsequently get a different error related to another similar problem with another private function).

PS unless you have a good reason for doing this, it's typically not a good idea to be making your own copies of toolbox code - it may well break, for these sort of reasons.

PPS you can tell that this is the problem by typing `which statsfminbx`, you'll see it's not found - but type `which -all statsfminbx` and you'll see it finds it, telling you that it's a private function to the `stats` folder.